# multiple nodejs apps for multiple domains on the same machine/ip. switching ports

Tags: node.js, dns, port

We have multiple domains each have embedded nodejs app we need to make every nodejs app running url like : http://domain_name:port_number

but we have a strange problem that every port we set for any nodejs app could be accessed from one domain not the domain we set the port in its nodejs app except 8080

How to make all ports accessible from all domains running on the same machine/ip or open port number for a domain

we use apache as the web server not using express or nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved there was a dns settings on cloudeflare prevents completing requests